# Materialized view for different oracle schema results in ORA-1208

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I want to create on commit materialized oracle view pointing to table from different schema within same database instance.

schema (BATCH):

```
CREATE TABLE "BATCH"."BATCH_CONFIG" 
   (    "KEY" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "VALUE" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
    "COMMENTS" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
    "UPDATED_BY" VARCHAR2(25 BYTE), 
    "UPDATED" TIMESTAMP (6), 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_BATCH_CONFIG" PRIMARY KEY ("KEY")
   );

create materialized view log on batch_config;
grant all on batch_config to profile;
```

schema (PROFILE):

```
create materialized view mv_batch_config REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT
        as select * from BATCH.batch_config;
```

Got Error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-12018: following error encountered during code generation for "PROFILE"."MV_BATCH_CONFIG"
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
12018. 0000 -  "following error encountered during code generation for \"%s\".\"%s\""
*Cause:    The refresh operations for the indicated materialized view could
           not be regenerated due to errors.
*Action:   Correct the problem indicated in the following error messages and
           repeat the operation.
```

What is the issue with ? I am able to view query by (from profile schema) select * from BATCH.batch_config

Comment: Do you have a primary key on your batch.batch_config table?

Comment: Yes.
CREATE TABLE "BATCH"."BATCH_CONFIG" 
   ( "KEY" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
 "VALUE" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
 "COMMENTS" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
 "UPDATED_BY" VARCHAR2(25 BYTE), 
 "UPDATED" TIMESTAMP (6), 
  CONSTRAINT "PK_BATCH_CONFIG" PRIMARY KEY ("KEY")
   )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK finally I got the solution.

I have to grant select on mview log also.

```
GRANT SELECT ON MLOG$_BATCH_CONFIG TO PROFILE;
```